# Eslint w/ Prettier & Typescript warning, how to remove it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier

I've just configured a React.JS project with Typescript, ESLint and Prettier. All working good, except I get this red warning line that won't dissapear in my index.tsx file:

[image]

How can I make this go away?

Here is what my .eslintrc.json file looks like:

```js
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [
      "warn",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "warn",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true
      }
    ],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": ["off"],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["warn"],
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and my .prettierrc file:

```js
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "printWidth": 80,
  "singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "auto"
}
```

and my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "devjam",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.32",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7"
  }
}
```

I assume eslint is conflicting with prettier somehow, yet I can't understand why on earth would there be a setting to add a comma after the closing bracket. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, as I want to start my project the right and clean way, without any kind of errors.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share index.tsx?

Comment: Also, tsconfig.json is relevant. Have you any .vscode/settings.json for the project? Or a vscode workspace? That configuration is relevant too.

Comment: What output do you get from running `npm run lint`